# When I do bitwise flip operation in C on integer 1, I get -2 and not 4294967294, how can I get 4294967294?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

It's one of the newbie HackerRank problems, where it asks to flip bits of a long represented by 32 bits, and return the value.

e.g.:

1 is represented as: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001

~ operator flips its bits.

so ~1 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110

When I do ~1 on a long, it returns -2, not 4294967294 despite both are represented equally in 32 bit binary form.

I implemented the code below:

```
long flippingBits(long n) {
    unsigned long m = n;
    unsigned long x = ~n;
    return x;
}
```

I got -2 as result. I tried with just "long", but got same result. I tried casting too with `unsigned long x = (unsigned long)~n;` but got same results again.

So then I just used XOR operation and it worked:

```
long flippingBits(long n) {
    unsigned long m = n;
    unsigned long x = n ^ 4294967295;
    return x;
}
```

Why ~ operation of 1 not represented as 4294967294 but -2 in C? What do I need to do to make ~ operator return 4294967294 and not -2 (if it's possible)?

Comment: You return the unsigned value as *signed*. When doing bitwise operations *always* use explicitly unsigned types. I recommend e.g. `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`.

Comment: Are you aware of the different representations for negative numbers? There are at least three 1-complement (what you tried), 2-complement (which is most widely spread as far as I know), sign (which is more for floats....). Read up on those keywords and explain what is still unclear. If that solves your problem let me know and I make an answer of this.

Comment: If on your machine `long` is represented on 32 bits, `4294967294` is outside the range of the `long` type (which is `[-2147483648, 2147483647]` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

On some platforms, `sizeof long == sizeof int`.

The standard defines the maximum value for an object of a `long int` to be `LONG_MAX`, where `LONG_MAX` must be at least `2,147,483,647`.

Thus, `4,294,967,294` can't be represented by a `long`.

---

### Fix:

- Always do bitwise operations on `unsigned` types.
- Change the return type of the function from `long` to `unsigned`.
- Use types like `int32_t` and `int64_t` defined in `stdint.h` header file, which are guaranteed to have `32` and `64` bits respectively.

Comment: Re “the minimum value… `LONG_MAX`”: The minimum value representable in a `long` is `LONG_MIN`. Perhaps you meant to say the standard specifies that standard defines `LONG_MAX` to be the maximum value representable in `long` and that the value of `LONG_MAX` must be at least 2,147,483,647, i.e., that the minimum maximum value of a `long` is 2,147,483,647. However, this is not relevant to the problem in OP’s code. Even if we change each `long` in their routine to `long long`, the problem persists. So it is not the width of `long` that is an issue; it is the misuse of a signed type.

Answer (score 1):

`~` is applied on an operand `n` which is of type signed `long`. Assuming 32 bit long then binary it will become `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110` indeed. But in decimal representation that means `-2` since the vast majority of real-world computers use *two's complement*.

When converted to `unsigned long` it does become `4294967294` however, because that's how signed to unsigned conversion works.

> I got -2 as result.

Upon return you convert back to signed again. This conversion is implementation-defined but likely you'll end up with `-2` again on all mainstream system. Similarly, if you would attempt to print an `unsigned long` using `printf("%ld", my_unsigned_long)` then it will likely display the signed decimal representation of what's stored inside the `unsigned long`.

> So then I just used XOR operation and it worked

In case of a 32 bit system, then one operand of `n ^ 4294967295`, namely the `4294967295` constant, is of type `long long` - because it can't fit in any smaller type. When the compiler tries to determine what type it will use for `4294967295`, it will ask itself: Does it fit inside an `int`? No. Does it fit inside a `long`? No. Does it fit inside a `long long`? Yes.

Therefore `1 ^ 4294967295` gives `4294967294` as expected, since the calculation is carried out on type `long long` and nothing affects the sign bit.

Answer (score 0):

Before using bitwise operators, you must consider several things :

1. Some combinations of padding bits might generate trap representations. [N1256 footnote](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#note44)
2. Two's complement is not the only way to encode a integer. [N1256 6.2.6.2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.6.2)

To satisfy above requirments, we use `uintN_t`  instead of `long`. `intN_t` doesn't have padding bits. And `uintN_t` is two's complement representation. `N` stands for width. For example, `int8_t` denotes a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits. The only problem is `uintN_t` is optional. [N1256 7.18.1.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.18.1.1)

> Why ~ operation of 1 not represented as 4294967294 but -2 in C? What do I need to do to make ~ operator return 4294967294 and not -2 (if it's possible)?

4294967294 is equal to `UINT32_MAX - 1`. So we choose `uint32_t`.

```
uint32_t flippingBits(uint32_t n)
{
    return ~n;
}
```

Comment: That code is the same as shown in the question. What changes did you intend to make?